# How can I add a bar to my application?

Tags: android, xml

I've added a text to the screen I have, a long one, the thing is there is a part which is missing, like moving the screen with my thumb to see whats below, but I can't.. Can I add bar to my screen/application so I would see the entire text that I added?

[image]

Comment: the bar is called a scrollview in android :)..

Comment: You may want a `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this. Like you can create ScrollView/Listview for this. These layouts will make your screen scrollable. So its upto you, which layout you want to use. There are many example on the internet related to Scrollview or listview layouts.

Comment: Thank you  Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille, Than and bimal chawla :)

Answer (score 0):

Add everything to ScrollView

ex.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <YourActualLayout
        parameters
        parameters>
           <Textview1/>
           <Textview2/>
           <Textview3/>
   </YourActualLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Remebmber that scrollview can have only one direct child(YourActualLayout) and that direct child may contain many other child(Textview1..) components in it like textview, imgaeview or edittext.

@edit

Or as suggested by @bimal chawla put it in ListView